# Kotlin extension function access Java private field

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-extension, kotlin-interop

I'd like to access Java's **private field** when using Kotlin **extension function**.

Suppose I have a **Java** class `ABC`. `ABC` has only one private field `mPrivateField`. I'd like to write an extension function in Kotlin which uses that field for whatever reason.

```
public class ABC {
    private int mPrivateField;

}
```

the **Kotlin** function would be:

```
private fun ABC.testExtFunc() {
    val canIAccess = this.mPrivateField;
}
```

the error I'm getting is:

`Cannot access 'mPrivateField': It is private in 'ABC'`

Any way of **getting around** that limitation?

Comment: why did you need to access the java **private** field?

Comment: it is from an external, compiled library that I'd like to extend without including the whole source code in my project. The library has "get" methods for the Android Calendar events and I wanted to add the "insert calendar event" functionality into to class.

Comment: modifying the external library **private** field is *dangerous*. it maybe crush your application. you can using java [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html) to change the field value.

Comment: Yeah, I'd agree. But I Just want to **get** that field. And use its methods just as the class that I'm extending does. No real threat here....

Answer (score 65, accepted):

First, you need to obtain a [Field](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html) and enable it can be **accessible** in Kotlin, for example:

```
val field = ABC::class.java.getDeclaredField("mPrivateField")

field.isAccessible = true
```

Then, you can read the field value as `Int` by [Field#getInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getInt-java.lang.Object-) from the instance of the declaring class, for example:

```
val it: ABC = TODO()

val value = field.getInt(it)
```

Last, your extension method is looks like as below:

```
private inline fun ABC.testExtFunc():Int {
    return javaClass.getDeclaredField("mPrivateField").let {
        it.isAccessible = true
        val value = it.getInt(this)
        //todo
        return@let value;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a clean solution which resolves the issue in an **inline** manner. No need to define a separate extension getter. Thanks

Comment: @kosiara-BartoszKosarzycki Of course, you can if you like, you can make the function to an **inline** function. Howerver, the extension is necessary when you want to make an operation abstract, for example: `testExtFunc(action:(Int)->R)`, separate the read logic from the `action` logic, and you can reuse the read function `testExtFunc` anywhere. then you can uses  it as, `testExtFunc(foo)` or `testExtFunc(bar)` they are just like as `let`/`run`/`apply` and .etc in kotlin.

Comment: How to get a field with type of listener, like `mOnCheckedChangeListener` in `CompoundButton`?

Answer (score 15):

That is not possible by design. Extension functions essentially resolve to static functions with the receiver as its first parameter. Thus, an extension function

```
fun String.foo() {
  println(this)
}
```

compiles to something like:

```
public static void foo(String $receiver) {
  System.out.println($receiver);
}
```

Now it's clear to see you cannot access private member of `$receiver`, since they're, well, private.

If you *really* want to access that member, you could do so using reflection, but you'll lose all guarantees.

Comment: Well I hope kotlin guys automate the reflection method generation to simplify private field getters in the future... although I agree that in most cases it's not safe

Comment: Well that's not gonna happen. No one should encourage reflection like that.

Comment: Anecdotal commit in the Android platform: [Another day, another private field accessed](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/81abb6fb7332dfe62ff596ffb250d8aec61895df%5E!/). In this case Google had to rollback the rename of a ***private*** member because Facebook was accessing it through reflection.

Answer (score 14):

Get private variable using below extension functions

```
fun <T : Any> T.getPrivateProperty(variableName: String): Any? {
    return javaClass.getDeclaredField(variableName).let { field ->
        field.isAccessible = true
        return@let field.get(this)
    }
}
```

Set private variable value get the variable

```
fun <T : Any> T.setAndReturnPrivateProperty(variableName: String, data: Any): Any? {
    return javaClass.getDeclaredField(variableName).let { field ->
        field.isAccessible = true
        field.set(this, data)
        return@let field.get(this)
    }
}
```

Get variable use:

```
val bool = <your_class_object>.getPrivateProperty("your_variable") as String
```

Set and get variable use:

```
val bool = <your_class_object>.setAndReturnPrivateProperty("your_variable", true) as Boolean
val str = <your_class_object>.setAndReturnPrivateProperty("your_variable", "Hello") as String
```

Comment: Super ! Works for me. Thx

Answer (score 3):

Just as **nhaarman** suggested I used **reflection** to access the field in question. Specifically I created a getter which used reflection internally on the class mentioned (that is `ABC`)

Sadly accessing private fields in Kotlin extension function is not possible as of *July 2017*

```
fun ABC.testExtFunc() {
    val canIAccess = this.getmPrivateField()
}

fun ABC.getmPrivateField() : Int {
    val field = this.javaClass.declaredFields
            .toList().filter { it.name == "mPrivateField" }.first()
    field.isAccessible = true
    val value = field.get(this)
    return value as Int
}
```

Comment: you can using `Class#getDeclaredField` & `Field#getInt` directly. since you know exactly what field you want to get.

Answer (score 1):

Extending **holi-java**'s answer with a generic type:

1. Create extension

```
fun<T: Any> T.accessField(fieldName: String): Any? {
    return javaClass.getDeclaredField(fieldName).let { field ->
        field.isAccessible = true
        return@let field.get(this)
    }
}
```

2. Access private field

```
val field = <your_object_instance_with_private_field>
                .accessField("<field_name>")
                    as <object_type_of_field_name>
```

Example:

```
class MyClass {

    private lateinit var mObject: MyObject

}

val privateField = MyClass()
                .accessField("mObject")
                    as MyObject
```